# objc_setAssociatedObject retain atomic or nonatomic

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

When I use `objc_setAssociatedObject`, I know whether to use retain or assign, but I don't know how to decide between `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN` and `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC`.  When should one or the other be used?

Comment: It probably depends on whether thread saftey is an issue and whether the calling object is itself defined as either atomic or nonatomic. There is a great answer here detailing the difference between these two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/whats-the-difference-between-the-atomic-and-nonatomic-attributes

Answer (score 15):

**Executive summary:** You must use `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN` if you might call `objc_setAssociatedObject` on one thread, and `objc_getAssociatedObject` on another thread, simultaneously, with the same `object` and `key` arguments.

**Gory details:**

You can look at the implementation of `objc_setAssociatedObject` in [`objc-references.mm`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-646/runtime/objc-references.mm). But actually the difference between `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN` and `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC` only matters for `objc_getAssociatedObject`.

Here are the definitions of those constants in `<objc/runtime.h>`:

```
enum {
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN = 0,           /**< Specifies a weak reference to the associated object. */
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC = 1, /**< Specifies a strong reference to the associated object. 
                                            *   The association is not made atomically. */
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC = 3,   /**< Specifies that the associated object is copied. 
                                            *   The association is not made atomically. */
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN = 01401,       /**< Specifies a strong reference to the associated object.
                                            *   The association is made atomically. */
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY = 01403          /**< Specifies that the associated object is copied.
                                            *   The association is made atomically. */
};
```

Note that `01401` is `0x0301` and `01403` is `0x0303`. The source code breaks these down further:

```
enum { 
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_SETTER_ASSIGN      = 0,
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_SETTER_RETAIN      = 1,
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_SETTER_COPY        = 3,            // NOTE:  both bits are set, so we can simply test 1 bit in releaseValue below.
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_GETTER_READ        = (0 << 8), 
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_GETTER_RETAIN      = (1 << 8), 
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_GETTER_AUTORELEASE = (2 << 8)
};
```

So we can see that `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC` is just `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_SETTER_RETAIN`, but `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN` is actually `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_SETTER_RETAIN | OBJC_ASSOCIATION_GETTER_RETAIN | OBJC_ASSOCIATION_GETTER_AUTORELEASE`.

The `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_GETTER_*` bits are examined in `_object_get_associative_reference`:

```
id _object_get_associative_reference(id object, void *key) {
    id value = nil;
    uintptr_t policy = OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN;
    {
        AssociationsManager manager;
        AssociationsHashMap &associations(manager.associations());
        disguised_ptr_t disguised_object = DISGUISE(object);
        AssociationsHashMap::iterator i = associations.find(disguised_object);
        if (i != associations.end()) {
            ObjectAssociationMap *refs = i->second;
            ObjectAssociationMap::iterator j = refs->find(key);
            if (j != refs->end()) {
                ObjcAssociation &entry = j->second;
                value = entry.value();
                policy = entry.policy();
                if (policy & OBJC_ASSOCIATION_GETTER_RETAIN) ((id(*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend)(value, SEL_retain);
            }
        }
    }
    if (value && (policy & OBJC_ASSOCIATION_GETTER_AUTORELEASE)) {
        ((id(*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend)(value, SEL_autorelease);
    }
    return value;
}
```

So if you use `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN`, it will retain and autorelease the associated object before returning it to you. But there's something else going on that's not obvious. Notice that the function creates a local instance of  `AssociationsManager` (which is a C++ object stored on the stack). Here's the definition of `AssociationsManager`:

```
class AssociationsManager {
    static spinlock_t _lock;
    static AssociationsHashMap *_map;               // associative references:  object pointer -> PtrPtrHashMap.
public:
    AssociationsManager()   { spinlock_lock(&_lock); }
    ~AssociationsManager()  { spinlock_unlock(&_lock); }

    AssociationsHashMap &associations() {
        if (_map == NULL)
            _map = new AssociationsHashMap();
        return *_map;
    }
};
```

So you can see that when the function creates its `AssociationsManager`, it acquires a lock, which it holds until the manager is destroyed. The destruction happens **after** the function has retained the associated object.

The same lock is used when setting a new associated object for the key. This lock prevents a race condition, where one thread is getting the associated object while another is replacing it and causing the object to be deallocated.

If you don't prevent the race condition, then someday your multithreaded app will crash (or worse) by trying to access a deallocated object. You can use `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN` to prevent the race condition, or you can ensure in some other way that you never set the association on one thread while getting it on another.

Comment: I ran into this exact race condition and your in-depth explanation helped me with fix so I owe you a thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the value you're trying to store would use the `nonatomic` attribute if it were a property, use `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC`, otherwise use `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN`.

Answer (score 0):

There are little reasons to use atomicity (`OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN`). In most cases thread safeness cannot be accomplished by making the data access thread safe. It is a bigger subject.

For properties there is the side-effect of atomicity that the read value is autoreleased. But neither is that documented for associated objects nor it is useful in ARC times.

So my advice: Use `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC`.